# Access Violation Writing Location with SDL_Net

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdl

I've been struggling with this for half a day and it hasn't improved, so here it's:
I have a class called Network Handler that will handle all network connections in a game I'm making in SDL, I'm using SDL_Net for all the networking. Here is my header class:

```
#ifndef NETWORK_HANDLER
#define NETWORK_HANDLER
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SDL_net.h>

using namespace std;

class NetworkHandler
{
public:
    NetworkHandler();
    ~NetworkHandler(){}
    bool Initialize(bool pIsServer);
    void CheckForMessages();
    void exit();
private:
    UDPpacket* m_packet;
    UDPsocket m_socket;
};

#endif
```

And here is my Class code:

```
#include "NetworkHandler.h"

NetworkHandler::NetworkHandler():m_packet(new UDPpacket()),m_socket(0)
{
}

bool NetworkHandler::Initialize(bool pIsServer)
{
    //Initialize SDL_net
    if(SDLNet_Init() < 0)
    {
        std::cerr<< "SDL Net Error:"<< SDLNet_GetError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    atexit(SDLNet_Quit);
    std::cout<< "SDL Net Error:"<< SDLNet_GetError() << std::endl;
    m_socket = SDLNet_UDP_Open(2000);
    if(!m_socket)
    {
        std::cerr<< "Socket Error:" <<SDLNet_GetError()<<std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    if(!(m_packet = SDLNet_AllocPacket(512)))
    {
        std::cerr<<"Packet Error:"<<SDLNet_GetError()<<std::endl;
    }

    if(!pIsServer)
    {
        IPaddress ip_server;
        if(SDLNet_ResolveHost(&ip_server,"10.167.193.140",2000)<0)
        {
            std::cerr<<"Failed to connect to Server: " << SDLNet_GetError() <<endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void NetworkHandler::CheckForMessages()
{
    if(SDLNet_UDP_Recv(m_socket,m_packet))
    {
        std::cout<<m_packet->data<<std::endl;
    }
}

void NetworkHandler::exit()
{
    SDLNet_FreePacket(m_packet);
    SDLNet_Quit();
}
```

I'm getting the following error:
*Unhandled exception at 0x00a3e524 in NetworkGameDevelopmenProject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcdcdcdd1.*

At this line:

```
m_socket = SDLNet_UDP_Open(2000);
```

And when I take a look at m_socket during debug, it has the following error attached to it:

```
m_socket    CXX0076: Error:
```

I've already tried cleaning and rebuilding. Funnily enough if I declare m_socket and m_packet locally(inside the function) it doesn't give me any errors. Can anyone think why this is happening?

Comment: How do you create the `NetworkHandler` object? It looks like it's been deleted or never properly created.

Comment: HA! Apparently that was it. I thought that C++ was taking care of initializing that object for me, since NetworkHandler is a member variable of another class. But it's really weird, because the code worked on a computer at my Uni, but not in my personal one, so I thought it had something to do with configuration or something similar. Thanks man! Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes.